# Rounding logic in Python?

Tags: python, rounding

In my original code I was trying to compute some indices out of some float values and I faced the following problem:

```
>>> print int((1.40-.3)/.05)
21
```

But:

```
>>> print ((1.40-.3)/.05)
22.0
```

I am speechless about what is going on. Can somebody please explain?

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: Why did I get a minus vote now??

Comment: I balanced it for you, Cupitor. +1.

Comment: @AaronHall, Thank you. I agree specially because of answers (e.g. the point about `print` by @delnan).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by floating point inaccuracy:

```
>>> print repr((1.40-.3)/.05)
21.999999999999996
```

You could try using the `Decimal` type instead:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> Decimal
<class 'decimal.Decimal'>
```

and then

```
>>> (Decimal('1.40') - Decimal('.3')) / Decimal('.05')
Decimal('22')
```

The `fractions.Fraction` class would work too. Or, you could just round:

```
>>> round((1.40-.3)/.05, 10) #  round to 10 decimal places
22.0
```

Comment: Although it's generally not the case that people *need* arbitrary precision. `21.999999999999996` is, for most practical purposes, `22`.

Comment: for most practical purposes except for `int()`

Comment: `Decimal` works fine... except when it doesn't. For example, `1/d * d != 1` in general. It's only accurate when you stick to certain simple operations.

Comment: So does that mean that I need to cast everything in my code to `Decimal`??

Comment: @Cupitor No, you could just round to 10 or so decimal places.

Comment: @Doorknob, I am actually reading the values from a file and retrieve them with `eval`. I cannot apply rounding or Decimal on eval. How can I correct this problem?

Comment: @Cupitor `eval`? I hope that file isn't from user input, and I hope it couldn't be edited by a malicious user. I'd recommend stopping that immediately and using `float` (as in `float("12.34")`) and rounding instead.

Comment: Ha ha! Thanks for the headsup. No this is a completely offline scientific program. But I didn't know that about float. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Drop the `print` and you'll see that the actual value is:

```
>>> (1.40-.3)/.05
21.999999999999996
```

Python 2 `print()` (more accurately, `float.__str__`) lies to you by rounding to a couple of decimal digits. Python 3 `print()` (again, actually `float.__str__`) doesn't do that, it always gives a faithful representation of the actual value (it abbreviates, but only when it doesn't change the value).

This inaccuracy is inherent to floating point numbers (including `Decimal`, though its inaccuracies occur different cases). This is a fundamental problem, representing arbitrary real numbers is not possible. See [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/395760) for explanations.

Comment: I see. But the "actual" value is 22.0!

Comment: @Cupitor What do you mean by "actual"?

Comment: I mean the real(mathematical) value of the expression.

Comment: @Cupitor you obviously haven't read the article from the first comment under your question. Real numbers cannot be represented by computers, only a subset of rational numbers.

Comment: @deathApril, no I didn't. I understand that computers can't. You wrote that `print` function lies by saying 22.0. I was just pointing out well in this case it is not a lie :)

Comment: @Cupitor It is a lie with regards to the value the program is actually dealing with. The rounding hides a very real error/inaccuracy in this case, but that doesn't make the error go away and in other cases it increases the error (e.g. for 1.0/3).

Comment: Yes that is true. Thanks anyways. I am quite happy to learn this about print().

Answer (score 0):

I think this explains it straightforwardly:

```
import decimal

>>> (decimal.Decimal(1.40) -decimal.Decimal(.3))/decimal.Decimal(.05)
Decimal('21.99999999999999722444243843')
>>> (decimal.Decimal('1.40') -decimal.Decimal('.3'))/decimal.Decimal('.05')
Decimal('22')
```